# InstallShield: Unwanted reboot after installed prerequisite

Tags: installshield, prerequisites, vcredist

I know there are already some posts about this issue but they seem old and the proposed solution won't work for me.

I have a Basic MSI project developed with InstallShield 2020 R3.

The setup has this prerequisite: "Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 redistributable Package (x86)".

After the prerequisite is installed, the following messagebox appears:

[image: Prompted MessageBox]

If I click "No", the setup will be terminated. If I click "Yes", the machine restarts but the setup doesn't resume after reboot.

However what I want is: after the prerequisite is installed, the setup will have to continue to the end without reboot and without showing any messagebox to the user.

I have already performed the following action:

I set the following values in the prerequisite editor:

[image: Application to Run]

[image: Behavior]

I have also tried to check "the prerequisite should be hidden from installation list"

and to select "Note it, fails to resume if the machine is rebooted and reboot after the installation".
I know that '3010' is the exit code for the vc_redist package when it asks for a reboot and for this reason I try to remove this value from the textbox "Specify the return code (in decimal)" the application return if a reboot is required"

What values do I have to set or what can I do in order to continue the setup without rebooting the system?

Comment: Hello Alessandro. Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: No sorry! I did not find a way to overcome this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try following option in ' If the prerequisite appears to need a reboot' dropdown:

> Note it, fail to resume if the machine is rebooted, and reboot after the installation.